# Add breaks to WordPress Nav Menu

Tags: php, wordpress

After searching for a solution to remove ul and li tags from a WordPress menu, I finally came across this:

```
<?php
$foot_nav = wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => '', 'echo' => '0', 'theme_location' =>     'registrations' ) );
$foot_nav2 = preg_replace( array( '#^<ul[^>]*>#', '#</ul>$#' ), '', $foot_nav );
$foot_nav2 = preg_replace( array( '#<li[^>]*>#', '#</li>$#' ), '', $foot_nav2 );
echo $foot_nav2;
?>
```

Works fine except I need to add a break after each link.

How can I accomplish this?

TIA :)

Comment: Why don't you use CSS ?

Comment: didn't want to remove ul and li on every menu only a few.. didn't feel like setting up a new class for the special menus

Answer (score 0):

It is usually possible in PHP to just add `/n` where you want a break.

Comment: Thanks.. \n didn't work but I realized it was reading it as HTML so I used <br> and that worked. Thanks for getting me on the right track.

Comment: You're welcome, just sorry I didn't give a more specific answer.